# How to get a better location accuracy in MyService

Tags: android, service

So my problem that MyService wasn't working correctly has ben resolved ... mostly. I first had a MainActivity with the following location method (removed unimportant stuff from the code):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{   

    private Context context;

    LocationManager locationmanager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        context=this;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);

        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        // Things that matter for this question below:

        locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria cri = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cri, false);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},0);
        }

        if (provider != null) {
            Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 60000, 0, this); //original (provider,minimalTime,minimalDistance,this); (provider,1800000,0,this) = 30 minutes; 0 distance change

            if (location != null) {
                onLocationChanged(location);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "location not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provider is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

My previous question, gave "another" method for location to use in MyService:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //Here you get lat and long
        try {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       // alarm below (not showed)
```

My 1st method in MainActivity, when connected to WIFI, the accuracy was either 30 meters or 1030 meters (about 50% of the time). With the 2nd method in MyService however, an accuracy of 1030 meter or higher was observed. I don't know for sure, but it is either the kind of provider or something with the kind of ACCES_FINE_LOCATION.

Thanks.

Comment: You're assuming a last known location is going to be available.  Don't do that- it frequently isn't.  YOur code will crash a LOT with null dereferences.  If you absolutely need a location you MUST register for location updates and wait for it to return one-  which could take several seconds->minutes (or never return if you can't get a GPS lock).

Comment: It doesn't crash at all. It sends the data (location, accuracy, current ip address, etc.) to my Google Form and implements them correctly. The problem is that it is not accurate enough to pinpoint a location, I need a solution to get an accuracy of 30 meters or less (with WIFI AND 3G/4G provider).

Comment: It will, frequently. You aren't null checking and you have to. And the accuracy here is what you get. You're using gps in your second method, there's no way to magically make it more accurate. Your top method isn't explicitly using gps, so could use network instead, explicitly asking for gps would ensure it doesn't, rather than using criteria (which is kind of a broken concept). Although you will sometimes get some low accuracy gps positions right as you initially lock, followed by more accurate ones as more data comes available. But the value should quickly converge.

Comment: However in your second method you aren't asking it for a new location (actually you aren't in your first either in the code shown), so you are using stale data. It's possible that it has a reduced accuracy claim to account for that. You should not be using get last known location, you should use request location updates if you need to track location our request single update for a one off

Comment: I would suggest to refer to Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). If you want to get location updates with better accuracy, exploiting all available providers you should use `FusedLocationProviderApi`. Depending on purpose (e.g. using location into an activity or tracking in background) you can receive periodic location updates either using a listener or through an `IntentService`. Please notice that your control over accuracy is based on priority you set, in your case probably `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`.